# Installing capistrano on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, capistrano

I'm having installation problems with Ubuntu in Ruby. I don't know anything about ruby and I would like to use capifony to deploy Symfony2 projects.

I already have successfully installed and used another rubygem to use sass, the css preprocessor.

I have the rubygems package installed.

First problem: when I try to install anything, the installation directory is /var/lib/gems/1.8 , and I'm not sure whether this is normal. I get permissions-related errors.

I solved this problem using sudo.

Second problem : I installed capistrano and whenever I try to use it I get errors:

```
cap deploy:setup           
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/capistrano-2.11.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-22 00:00:00.000000000Z"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem capistrano (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
        from /usr/local/bin/cap:18
```

I'm believe something is wrong with my installation but what? What would be the proper way to install a ruby gem on ubuntu ?
I'm not sure if the Invalid gemspec warning is critical, because I got other commands running fine without it.

Here is my `gem env` output:

```
gem env
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/capistrano-2.11.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-22 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/capistrano-2.11.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-22 00:00:00.000000000Z"
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.7.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/users/gparis/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Is it fair game to switch to `rvm`? Many people seem to prefer it for managing their Ruby experience separate from the distribution-provided packages.

Comment: Interesting... I suppose I need to uninstall the rubygems package first, don't I?

Comment: You solved my problem. Write an answer, maybe a bit more detailed, and I'll accept it.

Comment: The sad thing is, that's about my level of knowledge of `rvm`. You should write the answer, accept it, and reply so I can give you the upvote for explaining the work it took. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sarnold remark, I uninstalled the rubygem package, and installed rvm. I found installation instructions here : http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

The gem commands installed capifony in a directory I own, and I don't have these anoying messages anymore.

Comment: Your answer is not very helpful.